# Is there an error event on the object tag's data attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I've got an svg stored in an s3 bucket and I'm embedding it on an html page using the `object` tag, like so:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="url-to-svg-source" id="graph"></object>
```

Sometimes, when the browser tries to load the data from the url, it gets a 403. I'd like to notice this error and try reloading/re-rendering the svg source if it happens, but I can't tell how to notice this error. There must be a way to catch that error that I'm seeing printed in my js console in devtools. I've tried registering an eventListener "onerror", but it doesn't seem to be triggering. Maybe it's just that the error's occuring before my listener gets registered? Or maybe I'm registering it on the wrong object?

I've tried registering a listener on `error`, like so

```
document
  .getElementById("graph")
  .addEventListener(
    "error", 
    function(){ console.log("on error") })
```

Then I triggered an error from S3 like so

```
$("#graph").attr("data", badurl)
```

But I don't see my error listener firing..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I've been digging into this and it seems to me like browsers are inconsistent about how they're implementing this part of the HTML spec for `object` and I think it amounts to a bug in the browsers that I'm not seeing the error event fired consistently.

According to the [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/embedded-content-0.html#the-object-element), if the data attribute is present there are several steps the browser is supposed to execute to load the resource, and several points along the way where the browser is supposed to "fire a simple event named `error`" if the load fails. E.g., if it can't resolve the URL, if it can't fetch the resource, if it gets a 404, etc. However, it seems like different browsers are inconsistent in how they implement this spec.

If I save this html locally and load it in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, I see 3 different results.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>test object svg reload</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="main">
        <div>This object has valid data and loads a bee logo</div>
        <object type="image/svg+xml"
                data="https://www.beeminder.com/legacy_images/infinibee.svg"
                id="beelogo"
                onload="console.log('loaded bee logo')"
                onerror="console.log('error loading bee logo')">
          <h2 id="fallback">This is the fallback</h2>
        </object>
      </div>
      <div class="main">
        <div>This object will get a 404 when trying to load its data</div>
        <object type="image/svg+xml"
                data= "https://beeminder-dev.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/not-a-valid-file-name.svg"
                id="missinglogo"
                onload="console.log('loaded missing logo')"
                onerror="console.log('error loading missing logo')">
          <h2 id="fallback">This is the fallback</h2>
        </object>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In Chrome, both `onload` events are fired and I see "loaded bee logo" printed in the console, followed by "loaded missing logo".

In Safari, I see only "loaded bee logo" printed to the console.

In Firefox, I see "error loading missing logo", followed by "loaded bee logo" printed in the console.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such event name as `onerror`. Listen for `error` events instead:

```
addEventListener(
  'error',
  // ...
```

You'd use `onerror` only when assigning a handler via the setter, eg

```
<element>.onerror = () => {
  // do something
};
```

Comment: Ah, sorry! I made a stupid mistake there.. but I've just confirmed that I am not seeing my event listeners fire when they're registered with correct names using addEventListener. (editing my post now).